# Monthly Correlation for 19 variables

Tags: r

I have the following dataset with 21 columns - 19 variables and Month and Date as date type columns.

The aim is to analyze how correlation change over time calculating a daily correlation between variables summarized in one month. For example, see this "monthly correlation" over time. (X-axis as month type)

`+------------+---------+-----+-----+--------+---------+-------------+
| Date       | Month   | AOV | ASP | Clicks | Traffic | Impressions |
+------------+---------+-----+-----+--------+---------+-------------+
| 2017-01-01 | 2017-01 | 50  | 6   | 700    | 10000   | 4500        |
+------------+---------+-----+-----+--------+---------+-------------+
| 2017-01-02 | 2017-01 | 55  | 7   | 800    | 20000   | 4600        |
+------------+---------+-----+-----+--------+---------+-------------+
| 2017-02    | 2017-02 | 58  | 8   | 700    | 4599    | 2300        |
+------------+---------+-----+-----+--------+---------+-------------+`

At the moment I have the following  code but I only can compare two variables at the same time

```
ddply(corr,"Month",summarise,corr=cor(AOV,ASP))
```

I get the table below

`+---------+------------+
| Month   | corr       |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-1  | 0.4958738  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-10 | 0.8527522  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-11 | -0.2751771 |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-12 | NA         |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-2  | 0.6596346  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-3  | 0.6399969  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-4  | 0.7926245  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-5  | 0.6429613  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-6  | 0.3824414  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-7  | 0.9154873  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-8  | 0.7235767  |
+---------+------------+
| 2017-9  | 0.8264006  |
+---------+------------+`

I have been using combn to create the combinations set but I'm not quite sure how to use it with ddply. I get 171 combinations in pairs.

```
combn(corr,2,simplify = F)
```

Comment: Do not copy paste your data here like this. Provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:
`cor(your_data_frame)`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: can you explain what you are doing and how this works

Comment: Hi, that only will give you the overall correlation but I want to track correlation overtime.

Comment: HI Angelo, as commented above, if you can make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that would allow me and others to help.